# How to bind ports to systemd services for firewall configuration?

Tags: firewall, systemd

I would like to somehow bind the network ports a service needs to it's systemd configuration, so that the correlating ports are only open if the service is running properly.

Just adding trigger that add/remove firewall rules would not be a senible solution, since this would upset the ruleset order.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please consider that in general services are expected to run continuously.

In that regard dynamically opening and closing ports in your firewall when a service is either started or stopped does not achieve much of a benefit.

When a port is open in your firewall but  there is no listener to accept an incoming connection because the service is stopped/failed , that connection is going to be refused anyway.

---

> Just adding trigger that add/remove firewall rules would not be a sensible solution, since this would upset the ruleset order.

Although under the hood all  Linux flavours use iptables/netfiler for the actual firewall, rather than directly manipulating the rules most come with a userfriendly front-end to manage firewall settings.

Make your application work with those front-ends and there is much less risk that enabling/disabling  your service  will break things.

Systemd services are likely to come with firewalld - check for instance
https://firewalld.org/documentation/howto/add-a-service.html on how to define a firewall profile for your service.

Once your service is defined opening all ports associated with that service during runtime is then limited to a single command such as:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-service=myservice
```

and removing the service is similarly simple:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --remove-service=myservice
```

> I would like to somehow bind the network ports a service needs to it's systemd configuration, so that the correlating ports are only open if the service is running properly.

In your systemd service unit file use [`ExecStartPre=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStartPre=) with the appropriate command to open up the firewall before starting your service and close the ports again when the service has been stopped with [`ExecStopPost=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStopPost=).

```
[Unit]
Description=My service

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/my-simple-daemon -d
ExecStartPre=firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-service=myservice
ExecStopPost=firewall-cmd --zone=public --remove-service=myservice

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: That should probably be an `ExecStartPre=` so that the firewall port is opened before the service starts.